# QueryDsl maven plugin missing a class

Tags: eclipse, maven, querydsl

I am trying to configure my spring project to work with query dsl.
The maven build has a problem with the plugin and i am getting the following message:

```
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.4:process': Unable to load the mojo 'com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.4:process' in the plugin 'com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: org/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner
org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to me that you are using the wrong plugin artifact id. Shouldn't it be `maven-apt-plugin`. Take a look here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysema.maven/maven-apt-plugin/1.0.4

Comment: I am following the instructions here: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.8.2/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e114, i tried your suggestion and it didnt work as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dependency issue has been fixed in 1.0.6

https://github.com/mysema/maven-apt-plugin/issues/12

I will update the Querydsl docs

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a missing dependency.

Try to add this to your plugin dependency list:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I think the dependency should be on the plugin. I will edit my answer.

Comment: IT's been useful for me. I had only to change artifactId (apt-maven-plugin) for the correct spell (maven-apt-plugin)